# Бот discord пишет что пользователь не в сети, хотя он в сети, что делать? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx,member:discord.Member = None, guild: discord.Guild = None):
    if member == None:
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Информация о пользователе", color=ctx.message.author.color)
        emb.add_field(name="Имя:", value=ctx.message.author.display_name,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=ctx.message.author.id,inline=False)
        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.online:
            d = " В сети"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.offline:
            d = "⚪ Не в сети"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.idle:
            d = " Не активен"

        t = ctx.message.author.status
        if t == discord.Status.dnd:
            d = " Не беспокоить"

        emb.add_field(name="Активность:", value=d,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Статус:", value=ctx.message.author.activity,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Роль на сервере:", value=f"{ctx.message.author.top_role.mention}",inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Акаунт был создан:", value=ctx.message.author.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
        emb.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    else:
        emb = discord.Embed(title="Информация о пользователе", color=member.color)
        emb.add_field(name="Имя:", value=member.display_name,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Айди пользователя:", value=member.id,inline=False)
        t = member.status
        if t == discord.Status.online:
            d = " В сети"

        t = member.status
        if t == discord.Status.offline:
            d = "⚪ Не в сети"

        t = member.status
        if t == discord.Status.idle:
            d = " Не активен"

        t = member.status
        if t == discord.Status.dnd:
            d = " Не беспокоить"
        emb.add_field(name="Активность:", value=d,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Статус:", value=member.activity,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Роль на сервере:", value=f"{member.top_role.mention}",inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name="Акаунт был создан:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"),inline=False)
        emb.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

[image: Бот в "Активность" Пишет "⚪ Не в сети", хотя я в сети]

Comment: Нашёл ответ на вопрос, оставлю ссылку вдруг кому пригодится: https://qna.habr.com/q/1136666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = ctx.message.author.status

if str(t) == 'online':
    d = "✅В сети"

    if member.is_on_mobile():
        d = "✅В сети\nС телефона"

elif str(t) == 'offline':
    d = " Не в сети"

elif str(t) == 'idle':
     d = "Неактивен"

 elif str(t) == 'dnd':
      d = "Не беспокоить"
```

Источник: https://qna.habr.com/q/1136666

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]